# How to read body as string before sending request in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

In my performance tests in gatling I'm using ElFileBody to read xml, in which seqNumber will be used in one of the tags, so that each document is unique

```
<document>
<id>${seqNumber}</id>
</document>
```

Each unique document I want to then sign, so that I get:

```
<document>
<id>1</id>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo>...</ds:Signature>
</document>
```

I have tried to use processRequestBody however printing body.toString inside processRequestBody gives me "" so I'm not sure how to get the string value of xml and transform it to add a signature tag.

```
during(100 seconds) {
                forever("seqNumber") {
                    exec(http("Post New Document")
                      .post("/document")
                      .body(ElFileBody("bodies/document.xml"))
                        .processRequestBody
                        ({ body => {
                          print(body.toString)
                          val xml = signatureHelper.sign(body.toString);
                          StringBody(xml)
                        }})
                      .processRequestBody(gzipBody)
                      .header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                      .header("Content-Encoding", 
        "gzip").check(status.not(400),status.not(500))).exitHereIfFailed
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you sure it's picking up the xml file correctly and that 'body' is not actually empty?

Comment: No, the body is not empty, if I remove ".processRequestBody ({ body => {...}})" then the xml from the file is read correctly and then sent as zipped content (it's just not signed, but the request is sent with the body).

Comment: I expect `print(body.toString)` to output `"<function1>"`, because `ElFileBody.apply` returns a `CompositeByteArrayBody`, which is an `Expression`.

Comment: If my guess is correct, I think you can write `ElFileBody("bodies/document.xml").map(signatureHelper.sign _)`.

Comment: When I try it I get "Cannot resolve symbol map", do you think this could be some scala/Gatling version incompatibility?

Comment: I have tried SignatureCalculator as well but it turns out that I can read body there but not modify it: `.sign(new SignatureCalculator {
def sign(request: Request): Unit = {
val xml = signatureHelper.sign( request.getBody().getContent().toString )
 //printing xml with sinature works
 println(xml)
 //setting header works , but there is no way to modify the body
 request.getHeaders.add("X-Token", "foo")
}})`

Comment: Finally it worked with .map however I first assigned ElFileBody to value `val exp = ElFileBody("bodies/result.xml")` and then used it with StringBody `StringBody(session =>  exp(session).map(f => signatureHelper.sign(f.toString()))`

Comment: For `.map` on `Expression`s to work, you need to `import io.gatling.core.session.RichExpression`. I thought it was already included in the `Predef` imports. Sorry for not responding earlier, I did not receive a notification of your comments. You can tag me next time.